# MultitThreading in WinForms with Monitor, inconsistent order

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, queue, monitor

So I'm pretty new to Multithreading, I took some youtube lessons, had a read and just making try-out applications.

I would like this 'question' to be a good example (in the end, after some nice answers), how to deal with multithreading for people that just got into multithreading. I will update this post so it will be a good reference for further readers.

**Update 1:** Changed the way of locking, I thought `Monitor` was 'better', but that just depends on what you want. Code is edited cording to answer from @hatchat. My first path is still available to see in `LoadAllData()` while the new way is in `SaveData()`, Also updated questions with answers and more speculations.

So I did some testing, I want to have one object, named `Databases` to execute database commands, obviously. My goal is to save data while continue working without the user seeing any performance issues. Some requirements:

- I have to be able to send dataset to the class that needs to be updated in the database.
- I need to be able to retrieve data from the database and get it back as a dataset.
- I have to be able to call different tables that are associated to a `customerId`.

So I have 2 forms, one receiving all data and one form that only shows one table (when a customer is selected from form1). I'm just showing you all the code if you don't mind, in Form1 the most important button is `btnLoadAll` and in Form 2 the most important code is in the `btnSave` event.

Form1:

```cs
public delegate void ReturnDelegateDataSet(DataSet data); //used to return data to the main thread, used in form1 and form2

public partial class MultiThread_w_database : Form
{
    DataSet allCustomersData;
    private int currentSelectedCustomer = -1;

    public MultiThread_w_database()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnLoadSelected.Enabled = false;
        allCustomersData = new DataSet();
    }

    private void btnLoadAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//normally this would happen on formLoad
        //we want to return a dataset, so we have to use a delegate.
        ReturnDelegateDataSet delegateReturn = new ReturnDelegateDataSet(returnMethod1);

        ThreadDatabase data = new ThreadDatabase(delegateReturn);
        listBox1.Items.Add("creating Thread.." + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ms"));
        Thread loadThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(data.LoadAllData));
        listBox1.Items.Add("Starting Thread.." + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ms"));
        loadThread.Start();
        listBox1.Items.Add("Thread running, waiting for join.." + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ms"));
        loadThread.Join(60000);//so we are sure it should take longer then 5 seconds
        //now .Join still makes the app freeze, but we try to make sure that we don't load data
        //if we are still saving data.
        if(allCustomersData != null)
        {
            dgvCustomers.DataSource = allCustomersData.Tables["allCustomers"];
            dgvSecondTable.DataSource = allCustomersData.Tables["secondTable"];
            listBox1.Items.Add("thread is back and datasource is set" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ms"));
        }
        listBox1.Items.Add("end of buttonEvent");
    }

    //method is used to return the dataset
    public void returnMethod1(DataSet data)
    {
        allCustomersData = data;
    }
```

There are 2 more methods for checking what row is selected, and thus what customerId and one for opening the other form which passes through the customerId (if not -1)

Now for my Form2:

```cs
public partial class MultiThread_w_Database2 : Form
{
    DataSet currentCustomer;
    private int currentSelectedCustomer = -1;

    //I have this as global so I could recieve the reportString from that object
    //we can't do console.writeline in here and you can't access form controls from
    //another thread, not easy at least.
    ThreadDatabase dataSave;

    public MultiThread_w_Database2(int customerId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        currentSelectedCustomer = customerId;

        //just giving datasource to datagridview, same like before.

        //Like I said, global so I could receive the report strings from every action
        dataSave = new ThreadDatabase(currentCustomer, currentSelectedCustomer);
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   //magic happening here, btw for some good reason it really saves the data
        //even if we give the dataset already in the constructor of this form :)
        if(currentSelectedCustomer != -1 && currentCustomer != null)
        {
            Thread saveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(dataSave.SaveData));
            saveThread.Start();
        }

    }
```

There are 2 more methods, one for the timer to show the logging, and one for the callback method, only used on startup of that form.

Now for the database class, most important pieces are `LoadAllData()`, `LoadCertainData()` and `SaveData()`:

```cs
    static object locker = new object();
    private DataSet currentData;
    private SqlDataAdapter adapt;
    private int customerId = -1; //if none, -1, might be useful for testing before calling function
    private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["somestring"].ConnectionString;
    private ReturnDelegateDataSet callbackData;
    private string reportString = ""; //using for reporting back
    //CONSTRUCTORS
    //constructor for multiThread load ALL data
    public ThreadDatabase(ReturnDelegateDataSet callback)
    {
        currentData = new DataSet();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
        callbackData = callback;

    }

    //constructor for getting data associated to a customer.
    public ThreadDatabase(int customerId, ReturnDelegateDataSet callback)
    {
        currentData = new DataSet();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
        this.customerId = customerId;
        callbackData = callback;
    }

    //constructor for multithread Send Data
    public ThreadDatabase(DataSet dataNededToUpload, int customerId)
    {
        currentData = dataNededToUpload;
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();

    }

    //here is a property for returning reportString

    //METHODS
    //just load all data
    public void LoadAllData() //must be void, since we will return dataset via delegate
    {
        Monitor.Enter(locker);
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //doo some stuff to get data, fill in currentData Dataset, 2 tables.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { throw e;}
        finally
        {

            Monitor.Exit(locker);

        }
        if(callbackData !=null) //'return'  dataset
        {
            callbackData(currentData);
        }

    }

    //load data for one customer
    public void LoadCertainData()
    {

         if (Monitor.TryEnter(locker, 10000)) //with timeout
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    currentData.Tables.Clear(); //here we load another table, assosiated with the customer
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SecondTable WHERE customerId = @0", conn);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", customerId);
                    currentData.Tables.Add("OneCustomers");
                    adapt.SelectCommand = comm;
                    adapt.Fill(currentData.Tables["OneCustomers"]);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(locker);
            }
            if (callbackData != null) //'return'  dataset
            {
                callbackData(currentData);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //do other stuff
        }


    }

    //save edited data
    public void SaveData()//use dataset and customerId from constructor.
    {
        reportString += Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "trying to Aquire Lock " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ms") + "\n";
        lock (locker)
        {
            reportString += Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "lock aquired, updateing database" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ms") + "\n";
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connect.Open();
                SqlCommandBuilder commbuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapt);
                adapt.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SecondTable WHERE customerId = " + customerId, connect);
                adapt.Update(currentData.Tables["OneCustomers"]);
            }
            reportString += Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "closing lock" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ms") + "\n";
        }


    }
```

Test results:

[image: testResults]

For bigger: [click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL63Z.png)

Questions you are looking for?

1. Why is Form1 (on the left in the image) able to break trough the lock, one time it does wait for the lock to be opened again, but mostly not, even though it is calling another method, it should use the same lock. I'm happy with the results that, first it does not crash my application, second it doesn't save at the same time, but only from the same form then I guess.
2. I've tried using Monitor.TryEnter with interval, this caused sometimes to leave the lock locked I did that just like where I call the method: `LoadCertainData()` in Database class... **fixed this now, correct method is shown in code**
3. I thought this monitor was able to acquire the locks in order they come in, in the image I've numbered what order I clicked (datagridview) and what order it executed. It is not doing in the correct order, looks like the last one comes first. I couldn't figure out how [this queuing works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
   **turns out it doesn't.**
4. Last but not least, is this considered ThreadSafe? Am I heading into the good direction?
   **considered no first, still have to fix the correct method for returning objects (the Dataset)** I guess it is not a good idea to use the same class both for non-multithreading methods and multitheading functions?

For `1.` I would think it is because we create another instance of the Database object, In my opinion the static object should fix that issue, since it does clearly in form2.
**edit:** According to @Hatchet I was right about this, but that makes me think: I create 6 new instances of form2, thus creating 6 more instances of `ThreadDatabase`, so why are those 6 in Sync, meaning they don't obtain a lock at the same time. while form1 is able to aquire a lock at the same time. What I did notice: When another thread (in form2) already aquired the lock, form1 will wait until it is open. However, once that lock is open, both form1 and form2 are able to acquire the lock.

*I do know that in the image I can easily edit the Id's of the table, it is just for testing, I know my ways around that*

Comment: You shouldn't be using multi-threading. The tutorials are horrendously out of date. Use a single threaded asynchronous approach.

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll check that out Aron, thanks, but I thought this was the whole magic around multithreading, keeping the GUI running smoothly while doing some things in the background.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on multithreading, but it looks like there are some problems in your code. One is that, although Monitor is available in .Net, and valid to use, I think most people probably don't use it except in specific cases. So, your code ends up looking old fashioned. There are things available in c# that are much more normal to see in multitasking code. A big example would be the `lock` statement. This:

```
lock(lockObj) {
    // do stuff
}
```

is equivalent to

```
bool lockWasTaken = false;
var temp = lockObj;
try { 
    Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken);
    { // do stuff }
} finally { 
    if (lockWasTaken) Monitor.Exit(temp); 
}
```

The `lock` statement is easier, cleaner, more common, and more robust than what you're doing.

Your use of `Monitor.TryEnter` is wrong. You attempt to get a lock, and if you don't get the lock after 10 seconds, you just charge ahead and do the thing you are purportedly trying to synchronize with the lock. I don't understand why you're using `TryEnter`. You should use `Enter` if you want to block until you can obtain the lock. You should use `TryEnter` if you want to try and get the lock, and if you can't, then just not do whatever you are protecting with the lock. For example:

```
  if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj, 10000)) {
     try {
        // do stuff that required a lock
     } finally {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
     }
  } else {
     // do something else when you couldn't get a lock
  }
```

I'm wondering whether you're thinking conceptually about the purpose of a lock correctly. Don't think of it as protecting some code. It's for protecting the integrity of shared resources by synchronizing access to those resources. To know where to lock, you need to know what requires protection. There are all sorts of problems that can crop up with shared resources and locks. You have to use locks where needed, but that said, you also should use them only where needed, and in as small a scope as is necessary. It's easy to get wrong, and when you do, the problems and symptoms of doing it wrong can be very subtle and seemingly weird.

Question #1 I think is partly covered above. I'll also add that you are correct that since you create two instances of ThreadDatabase, there is no synchronization between those two instance. This is because each instance has its own lock object. A lock on an object will not block an attempt to lock on a different object.

Question #2 covered above

Regarding question #3, you don't really 'execute' a lock. You obtain/acquire a lock. I don't think you should be thinking of order. Once you start a number of threads, it's kind of out of your hands when, and in what order they arrive at a particular point in code. There isn't a 'correct' order.

Question #4: I'm pretty sure it's not threadsafe, if for nothing else, because of the incorrect use of `TryEnter`. But I think there are likely other issues too. For example, your methods in ThreadDatabase return currentData, a private instance member, and once handed out like that, access to it is not protected by any synchronization.

If you want a pretty thorough resource for multithreading with C# that's fairly up-to-date, I recommend [Albahari's Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). He covers the features available, and discusses many of the hidden pitfalls that lurk.

Comment: Thanks for that link, seems like a good one. I've updated my post